# Subtract from zero not working in query

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `page` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `sortorder` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

This is the data I have:

```
id  sortorder
1   0
2   1
```

And I want to run this query:

```
select id from page where (sortorder = (select sortorder from page where id = 1) - 1)
```

(I'm trying to find the previous page, ie the one with the lower sortorder, if it exists. If none exists, I want an empty result set.)

The error I receive from mysql:

```
SQL Error (1690): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '((select '0' from `page` where 1) - 1)'
```

And more specifically when I run:

```
select sortorder - 1 from page where id = 1
```

I get:

```
SQL Error (1690): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '('0' - 1)'
```

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Also, when I run the query with '+ 1', I get the desired result, namely id 2 in this case.

Comment: The solution to your problem uses a `JOIN` of table `page` against itself.

Comment: According to your error message, you're running on `BIGINT UNSIGNED`. This type does not support negative values.

Comment: @kasoban sigh you are correct, I seem to be blind today, or just not paying attention to the meaning of the word 'unsigned'...

Comment: @axiac wouldn't I still have to do a - 1 somewhere?

Comment: @Torminator Indeed, I wrote the query I had in my head and I received the same error message because of the `UNSIGNED`. However, you can put `+1` (instead of `-1`) to the other side of the equal sign and it works. My remark about using `JOIN`, in fact, addresses the final goal, not the MySQL error.

Comment: @axiac my my, my brain is really dead it seems. When I put the + 1 on the other side, everything works (with my query too, and I would need to profile to see if joining works faster or not, but for this case it seems pointless). Basic math.. :-) Thanks for helping me think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use `JOIN`s for this goal because they can be optimized better than the sub-queries. This query should produce the same result as yours but probably faster:

```
SELECT pp.*
FROM page cp             # 'cp' from 'current page'
  LEFT JOIN page pp      # 'pp' from 'previous page'
        ON pp.sortorder = cp.sortorder - 1
WHERE cp.id = 1
```

Unfortunately it fails running with the same error message about `-1` not being `UNSIGNED`.

It can be fixed by writing the `JOIN` condition as:

```
        ON pp.sortorder + 1 = cp.sortorder
```

I moved the `-1` to the other side of the equal sign and it turned to `+1`.

You can also fix your original query by using the same trick: moving `-1` to the other side of the equal sign; this way it becomes `+1` and there is no error any more:

```
select id
from page
where (sortorder + 1 = (select sortorder from page where id = 1)
```

The problem with both queries now is that, because there is no index on column `sortorder`, MySQL is forced to check all the rows one by one until it finds one matching the `WHERE` (or `ON`) condition and this takes a lot of time and uses a lot of resources.

Fortunately, this can be fixed easily by adding an index on column `sortorder`:

```
ALTER TABLE page ADD INDEX(sortorder);
```

Now both queries can be used. The one using `JOIN` (and the `ON` condition with `+1`) is slightly faster.

The original query doesn't return any rows when the condition is not met. The `JOIN` query returns a row full of `NULL`s. It can be modified to return no rows by replacing `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`.

You can circumvent the error altogether (and use any version of these queries) by removing the `UNSIGNED` attribute from column `sortorder`:

```
ALTER TABLE page 
CHANGE COLUMN `sortorder` `sortorder` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the full answer! I could indeed do the tweak of the index. The reason I chose sortorder to be an unsigned integer was because the order will never be negative anyway, so it seemed a waste of integer space (not as if I'll have 65k pages anyway, but still..)

Comment: No matter of signed/unsigned issue, you still need an index on `sortorder` if you want to use it efficiently in `WHERE`, `ON`, `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` clauses. Put [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) in front of the queries to check how MySQL plans to run them and what indexes it uses.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your SQL Mode in 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION'

```
SET sql_mode =  'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION'
```

Comment: Yes, this would work too, but it seems a bit annoying to do for a single query. Still, your answer is correct, per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html (and I think the `SELECT CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) - 1;` is important too)

Comment: SELECT CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) - 1 is similar to(select sortorder from page where id = 1) - 1

Comment: Yes, but with my SMALLINT being UNSIGNED, the cast is still necessary according to the help page.

Comment: I don't think the cast is important here and in this example, 0 is being 'CASTED' as UNSIGNED. In your table, the sortorder is itself unsigned, so no need to cast it again.
This was there in the help page when the sql_mode was not set:
    mysql> SELECT CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) - 1;
    ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(cast(0 as unsigned) - 1)'